Flutter - change parameters at build time (AdMob ID)
I am using Flutter with the Google AdMob lib and have this helper Class AdManager (part of the example somewhere) that manages the IDs.
class AdManager {

  static String get bannerAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-TEST_ID';
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // return 'ca-app-pub-MY_APP_ID';
      return 'ca-app-pub-TEST_ID';
    }
    throw UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
  }

  static String get nativeAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-TEST_ID';
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // return 'ca-app-pub-MY_APP_ID';
      return 'ca-app-pub-TEST_ID';
    }
    throw UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
  }
}

How can I change the return of the class during compilation. I understand one should only use ca-app-pub-TEST_ID during testing and switch to the real IDs 'ca-app-pub-MY_APP_ID' in the PROD version only. How can I do this during the package build.
Right now I am focussing only on iOS so what I do is to open XCode and build the archive manually. There may be automated Flutter commands (which are those?) to build and ways to define the IDs at compile time so I do not have to switch back and fort manually. Using VSCode.
Thanks!

You can probably solve it using flavors: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors
The idea is that you'd have a flavor for each build.
Then at runtime you can check the compiled flavor using the appFlavor constant: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/appFlavor-constant.html
So in practise it would be something like:
flutter build appbundle --flavor id1
Then at runtime you'd check the appFlavor constant:
if (appFlavor == 'id1') {
  return 'id-for-this-flavor';
}

I think this will solve your problem.
